# Magento2: How to locate file in destination using the move element.

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, toplinks

I'm  been looking through my default.xml trying to add links to top.links. In the default.xml file I see this.

```
<move element="top.links" destination="rd.navbar.collapse.items"/>
```

so I know this tag displays the header link, but what file is destination pointing too?  I cannot find the name "rd.navbar.collapse.items" any where in my directory tree.  thanks!